# There was an error in evaluating the test script:

Tags: postman

I am currently working on postman 30-day challenge where I am simply doing the fork of the daily project given in this project I am dealing with the collections and environments.

I have done what they said and at last when I run the test the problem is:

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'item')

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]